# How do I capture if the enter key has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm trying to capture if the enter key has been pressed and execute a search. This is the viewmodel for the search page.

```
(function () 
{
    a.viewModels.userSearch = function (view, params) {
        $view = $(view);
        var self = a.viewModel({
            users: a.collection({
                url: '/admin/Account/SearchUsers',
                query: {
                        SearchText: null
                       }
            }).fetch(),
            setPageIndex: setPageIndex,
            search: search
        });

        $view.keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                self.search(e);
            }
        });

        function search(e) {
            self.users.query.rowCount = 0;
            self.users.query.pageIndex = 1;
            self.users.fetch();
        }

        function setPageIndex(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            self.users.query.set('pageIndex', $(e.currentTarget).data('page-index'));
            self.users.fetch();
        }

        return self;
    }
```

Now, this works. The problem is that it works only after pressing the 'Enter' key 2 times. Seems like I'm missing something related to the scope but js ain't my cup of tea.

If it is of any help, here goes my view model function:

```
function viewModel(viewModelConfig) {

    var self = kendo.observable($.extend({
        busy: 0,
        resultMessage: null,
        clearResultMessage: clearResultMessage
    }, viewModelConfig));
    self.bind('change', onChange);

    function onChange(change) {
        var errorProp, errorMsg, infoProp, infoMsg;
        if (change.field.endsWith('.busy')) {
            if (self.get(change.field))
                self.set('busy', self.busy + 1);
            else if (self.busy > 0)
                self.set('busy', self.busy - 1);
        }
        else if (change.field.endsWith('.resultMessage')) {
            var data = self.get(change.field);
            self.set('resultMessage', data);
        }
    }

    function clearResultMessage(e)
    {
        if (e) e.preventDefault();
        self.set('resultMessage', null);
        return false;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup on my site, and using MVVM, just add the custom `enter` binding within the `data-bind` attribute of the element to link to the function within the view-model you wish to execute.

The code to add the custom binder is as such:

```
kendo.data.binders.widget.enter = kendo.data.Binder.extend({
    init: function(element, bindings, options) {
        kendo.data.Binder.fn.init.call(this, element, bindings, options);
        var binding = this.bindings.enter;
        $(element.element).keyup(function(e) {
            if( e.which === 13 )
                bindings.get();
        });
    },
    refresh: $.noop
});
```